# Is this a valid HTTP response?

Tags: http

I am writing a web server using C++, which responds the following for all requests:

```
static std::string rsp[] = { 
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n",
    "Server: WebServer\r\n",
    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n",
    "Content-Length: 3\r\n",
    "Connection: close\r\n",
    "\r\n",
    "123"
};
```

the content "123" can be successfully shown in browser. But when I use apache-ab to do a test, ab always show errors like this:

```
ab -n 1 -c 1 http://127.0.0.1:1080/
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

I thought that I'm closing the socket too quickly, so I commented the close() function. But ab just hold, ab seems to be waiting for a complete response.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, MIME states that `\r\n` is the canonical line ending in the headers of a MIME document (which HTTP responses are).

Answer (score 2):

If you can correctly render the response (123) in your browser, then it means that there is nothing wrong with your server, but with the request ab is sending to your server is not understood by your server.

ab's requests are not necessarily the same as a web browser's requests. And ab is not fully http 1.1 complainant, it's a http1.0 client.

> "It (ab) does not implement HTTP/1.x fully; only accepts some 'expected'
>   forms of responses.

[Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

Try this:
0. See the request being sent to your server: `ab -n 5 -c 5 -v 10 http://127.0.0.1:8000/` using the verbosity argument. You should see something like this:

```
    GET / HTTP/1.0
    Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
    User-Agent: ApacheBench/2.3
    Accept: */*
```

1. Using firebug or something, get the requests being sent from your browser.
2. Now, match them, see what is the difference in the requests being sent. Use `ab -H` to send those custom headers to your web server from ab.

Comment: Thank you zengr. I've found the reason, my server is closing the socket too quickly. this can be solved by calling shutdown(fd,RD) instead of close(fd).

Comment: I am glad you found an answer.